# How to pull in a field from phone Call entity to activities entity ? CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a field called 'Follow up Owner ' in Phone Call Entity ' I would like to show the field on Open Activities View. I don't see a way to pull the field from Phone Call entity through Activities 'add Columns' options. Is there a way to do this ?
[image: Open Activities view]
[image: Follow up owner field on Phone call View]

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because your Follow-up owner field is related to phone call, not activity entity. As activity entity is non-customizable entity - you cannot add new field on Activity using supported CRM customization.
You could probably add this field on the Phonecall view instead of activities view - this should be working fine then.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for Assigned To/follow up owner field on activities view, so my users can easily identify the owner of the task/ to whom the task is assigned to.